# edit input readonly By web site developers tools

Tags: javascript, html

There is a programming flaw when using this code

```
<input id="result"name="v13" readonly>
```

When using read-only can adjust through tools developers and edit input value and the new value written by and are read-only
When collecting the numbers and show the value in the input box and are read-only can be modified through tools for developers in chrome and send the value

Is there a way to prevent the Edit Value ؟

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: You can adjust any client side code through developer tools, this is why you should still have validation on the backend.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the Edit Value

Comment: No. Browsers, malicious entities, cosmic rays, etc. may send you all sorts of evil inputs which your serverside application should be prepared for.

Comment: Don't forget the Crab People.

Comment: It's not a "flaw".  You can't control other users' web browsers.  Accept it and account for it in your designs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a programming flaw when using this code

No there isn't.

> Is there a way to prevent the Edit Value?

No.  All HTML code does, all it's ever done, is *suggest* to the client (the web browser generally) what should be done.  The user can override any of those suggestions any time they want.  Because the user is in control of their own computer and any code which executes on that computer.

Also of note, even if you *could* prevent the user from modifying your HTML, you still can't prevent the user from crafting their own HTTP request to send to your server, based on reverse-engineering your HTML, but which happens entirely outside of the context of your HTML and *pretends to be from* your HTML.

This is a critical thing to understand and account for in any client-server design, such as web applications...

***Never implicitly trust what you receive from the client.***

Users, whether malicious or curious or even entirely by accident, can send you any data they want any time they want.  There is nothing you can do to stop someone from sending you data from their own computer.  (If it gets *really* bad, such as a DOS attack, then there are network infrastructure options to prevent your application from receiving that data, but that's outside the scope of the application code itself.)

What you can and should do is meaningfully validate and respond to requests from users.  If a request is determined to be invalid in some way, you can return an error or attempt to redirect the user to proper use of the application or even simply ignore the request altogether.  But you can't stop the user from sending you the request.

Always validate the request.